# how to understand this syntax class obj= class.method;

Tags: java, android

have you ever seen this syntax in java

class obj= class.method;

TaskStackBuilder stack= TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

what does it mean ?

Comment: It is a call to an instance (static) method.

Comment: I'd rather write `TaskStackBuilder stack = new TaskStackBuilder;`

Comment: @Rotwang: Or even `TaskStackBuilder stack = new TaskStackBuilder(this);`

Comment: I suggest working through some Java tutorials.

Comment: It basically means "create a new object of type TaskStackBuilder and instance it".

Comment: but the "TaskStackBuilder"  is not a static ...............................    

public final class TaskStackBuilder implements Iterable<Intent> {
    private static final String TAG = "TaskStackBuilder";

Comment: @MahMSL: The *class* wouldn't be `static`. The `create` method in it absolutely is, if it's being called as shown above. And assuming it's [this Android SDK method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html#create(android.content.Context)), as you can see, it's `static` (the detail docs don't make that very clear at all, but it's clear in the method summary: `static TaskStackBuilder create(Context context)`).

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TaskStackBuilder stack= TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
> ```
>
> what does it mean ?

It means that the `TaskStackBuilder.create` returns an object of type `TaskStackBuilder`. Methods like that are usually called *builder* or *factory* methods.

Example:

```
class TaskStackBuilder {
    public static TaskStackBuilder create(Object obj) {
        return new TaskStackBuilder();
    }
}
```

Although of course, the one you're looking at would likely make use of `obj` (and use a more specific type for it).

Factory methods are particularly useful when object instances can be cached and reused. For instance, the `Integer` class caches [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) caches `Integer` instances for the values -128 throug 127, and may cache others, so when you do `Integer.valueOf(20)` (for example), you'll always get back the **same** instance of `Integer` (not just equivalent ones).

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you mean is the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabrikmethode) you can use this with a private class constructor to create an spezified instance.

The default constructor of your class is private:

```
public SomeClass{
     private SomeClass(){
     }
}
```

and for create an instance you call the create method, which can use the private consturctor to create an instance.

See also [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Where you want only one instance of the object:

public class Test{
    private static Test _instance = null;

```
private Test(){};

public Test getInstance(){
    if(Test._instance == null){
         _instance = new Test();
    }

    return Test._instance;
}
```

}